# Understanding spark sql custom join expression which contains map and reduce functions

Tags: dataframe, scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I am new to Big data and going through an existing code base and trying to understand a specific piece of code. I was struck while understanding a join expression used for joining two dataframes where reduce is being used as part of the expression. Here is the code which contains the join expression

```scala
 def joinOnMultipleColumns(leftDF: Dataset[Row], rightDF: Dataset[Row],
      leftColumns: List[String], rightColumns: List[String]
  ): DataFrame = {
   // Both leftColumns and rightColumns variables are of same length 
    val joinExpression = leftColumns
      .zip(rightColumns)
      .map { case (c1, c2) => col(c1) === col(c2) } 
      .reduce(_ && _)  // -----> what does the map and reduce part mean here

    rightDF.cache.show
    leftDF.join(rightDF, joinExpression)
  }
```

Please let me know if I need to provide any further information

As per my assumption, the function receives two column lists [t1_col1, t1_col2], [t2_col1, t2_col2] along with the two dataframes

- zip would result in (t1_col1, t2_col1), (t1_col2, t2_col2)
- map and reduce combined will create a join expression with col1===col2 but not sure what's happening exactly and my assumption might be completely wrong too

Can someone please help me in understanding what does the code actually do?

Comment: "will create a join expression with col1===col2 but not sure what's happening exactly" –– This _is_ exactly what's happening.

Comment: Could you please explain What does reduce(_&&_) means there?

Comment: check out [the doc](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.13.3/scala/collection/immutable/List.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Map is a high order function which responsible for transforming valuses in some collection by applying function passed to map to each value in the collection.
Let's dig into your code:

1. Assume you have following values:
   leftColumns = ["col1_1", "col1_2"] and rightColumn = ["col2_1", "col2_2"]
2. zip

```
leftColumns
.zip(rightColumns)
```

On this step we zip two initial collections of strings into one collection of tuples: `[("col1_1", "col2_1"),("col1_2", "col2_2")]`

3. map

```
.map { case (c1, c2) => col(c1) === col(c2) } //
```

As I said earlier, with map we need to apply some **function** to each **element** in the collection. **Element** of the collection is a tuple of (String,String). **Function** is a `col(left)===col(right)`. So it means we're transforming List[(String,String)] to List[Column] (because `===` applied to column will return column [=== in scaladoc](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/Column.html#===(other:Any):org.apache.spark.sql.Column))

Finaly we will get: `[col("col1_1") === col("col2_1"), col("col1_2") === col("col2_2")]`

4. reduce

```
.reduce(_ && _)
```

Reduce is responsible for folding collection of values into one value. In this case we're folding List[Column] to just Column by applying &&(And operator, which will return Column if we apply it to Column [&& in scaladoc](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/Column.html#&&(other:Any):org.apache.spark.sql.Column)

So finally we will get this: `col("col1_1") === col("col2_1") && col("col1_2") === col("col2_2")` which is set of conditions for joining 2 dataframes

Comment: Naive question, but how can we know which type of join is applied here. We are ensuring join based on these column values, but will it be left outer or right outer or inner join ?

Comment: By default it's inner join, but you have option of join function with third parameter where you can pass it. https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.0.0/api/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/Dataset.html#join(right:org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset[_],joinExprs:org.apache.spark.sql.Column,joinType:String):org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame